# Sum of expectations of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, divergent-series

I have a sequence of positive random variables $Xt$, and I am trying to determine the convergence of $$\sum_{t\ge1} \frac{1}{E(T_t)}.$$

I know that $$P(\limsup(Xt=O(t))=1.$$

This implies that $X_t\le ct$ infinitely often, and so  $\frac{1}{T_t} \ge \frac{1}{ct}$ i.o. , and I was hoping this would prove that $$\sum_{t\ge1} \frac{1}{E(T_t)} \geq  \sum_{t\ge1} \frac{1}{ct}=\infty $$

but since it can fail infinitely often this doesn’t hold. This could be resolved if $X_t < ct$ only finitely many times, however I was able to prove that
$$P(\liminf(Xt=O(t))=0,$$
and so $X_t <ct$ infinitely often as well.

Are there any other approaches I can take to see whether the sum will converge or diverge, probabilistically?

Comment: My intuition is that there is some catch. For example consider a series that satisfy $E(X_i)= i$ if i is a square number and infinity if i is not a square number, we can easily see the series converge in this case

Comment: @PrestonLui yes exactly! The fact that it is greater than $ct$ i.o. ruins my above argument. I am hoping to find new ideas to investigate convergence/divergence :)

Comment: My bet is on unless there is some weird special condition that must be satisfied, there would not be a definite answer. That said, my theoretical groundwork is too weak to make these kinds of speculation.

Comment: Are your random variables assumed to be positive?  If not, what if $X_{2t+1} = -X_{2t}$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes sorry, they are positive! Will edit the question now

Comment: Even if all $T_t = O(t)$ almost surely, it doesn't imply there is a fixed $c$ such that $T_t \le c t$.  E.g. you might have $T_t = t/U$ where random variable $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.  Then $\mathbb E[T_t]$ doesn't even exist.